# Сделать для Я.карт loading bar

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет. Использую для своих целей этот скрипт из песочницы.
[пример песочницы Я.карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager/) . Но у меня очень много точек (200 тыс), и при отрисовке кластеров есть задержка. Можно ли сделать что-то типа полосы загрузки, чтобы пользователь оценивал для себя скорость и время, которое осталось ждать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть идеи?)

Comment: А задержка точно при отрисовке кластеров, а не при получении данных? Если при получении, то может помочь https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress

Answer (score 0):

Для такого числа объектов используйте **[Слой активных областей](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/hotspots/about-hotspots.html)** или один из других предложенных [методов работы с большим числом объектов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/many-objects.html). Не нужно такое число объектов грузить в пользовательский браузер поштучно и изобретать методы времяпровождения во время загрузки.

Comment: Наверное, не так выразился. отрисовываю я через objectManager. Всё хорошо. быстро. Но в дальнейшем мне нужно фильтровать или пробегаться по атрибутам меток через jQuery.getJSON. Вот тут и появляется ожидание ответа.